# Issue displaying updated data in Vue component after axios POST

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm stuck on a problem and was hoping that a **Javascript Jedi** could help point me in the right direction.

**Scope of the problem:**

I'm passing a Laravel collection to my Vue component. Inside the component, I'm iterating through the collection and submitting a form via axios. The form submits, the data is updated in the database, but **__I'm not clear on how to show the updated value without a page refresh.__**

**Expected Outcome:**

The updated data is reflected in the `{{ collection.value }}` inside the Vue template after form submission

**What's going wrong:**

The data is being updated in the database, but the `{{ collection.value }}` remains the same until page is reloaded.

**Web.php**:

```
Route::post('/updateQty', 'MyController@update');
```

**MyController**:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::where('id', $request->productId)
        ->update([ 'qty' => $request->qty ]);

    return response()->json($product);
}


public function index()
{

    $collection = DB::table('products')->get();

    return view('my-blade', [
        'collections' => $collection,
    ]);

}
```

**Structure of $collection as stored in the database**:

```
'qty' => decimal(8,2),
'class' => varchar(255),
'description' => varchar(255),
'value' => decimal(8,2),
'productId' => int(11)
```

**my-blade**:

```
<my-component :collections="{{ $collections }}"></my-component>
```

**MyComponent.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <div v-if="collections.length">
                        <tr v-for="collection in collections" v-bind:key="collection.id">
                            <td>
                                <form @submit="updateQty">
                                <input type="hidden" id="productId" :value="collection.productId" name="productId">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="qty" id="qty" @change="updateQty">
                                        <option :value="collection.qty">{{ collection.qty }}</option>
                                        <option v-for="(x, index) in 200" v-bind:key="index" :value="index">{{ index }}</option> 
                                </select>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ collection.value }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
    props: ['collections'],

    data() {
        return {
            qty: '',
        }
    }

    mounted() {
        console.log('MyComponent.vue mounted successfully');
    },

    methods: {

        updateQty(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let currentObj = this;
            let url = '/updateQty';

            axios.post(url, {
                qty: qty.value,
            })

            .then(function (response) {
                currentObj.value = (response.data);
                let collections = response.data;
            })
        },

    }
}
</script>
```

**App.js**

```
Vue.component('my-component', require('./components/MyComponent.vue'));
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but for the life of me I can't wrap my head around it. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change up your script a bit.

First, save the collections property to a data property, or Vue will scream when you try to update it.  To do this, I would rename the incoming `prop` as something like `collections_prop`.  Then save it to the `collections` data property.

Then change `let collections =` to `this.collections =` in your update response.

**EDIT:** I changed the `.then` function to ES6 syntax as you may have trouble accessing the `this` variable otherwise. No need for the `currentObj` stuff.

```
export default {
    props: ['collections_prop'],

    mounted() {
        console.log('MyComponent.vue mounted successfully');
    },
    data() {
        return {
            collections: this.collections_prop;
        }
    },
    methods: {

        updateQty(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let url = '/updateQty';

            // not sure where qty is coming from 
            // but you said that's all worked out
            // on your end

            axios.post(url, {
                qty: qty.value,
            })

            .then(response => {
                this.collections = response.data;
            })
        },

    }
}
```

And finally, don't forget to update the prop in your view.

```php
<my-component :collections_prop="{{ $collections }}"></my-component>
```

Or if you want to later specify prop type as JSON:

```php
<my-component :collections_prop='@json($collections)'></my-component>
```

Comment: Hey @matticustard ! Thanks for helping me out with this. I really appreciate it! For clarity, the qty definitely submits and it updates the record in the database. I'll update my question with the contents of the $collections array, if that helps?

Comment: Interesting.  How is it that you are accessing the `qty` variable in `updateQty` when it's never clearly defined?  Can you point to the documentation for this feature?  I'm just curious how it's done.

Comment: My apologies! I just tried to re-write this sample code from the actual and just left it out by accident. I have qty listed under data() - I'll update my answer. Not a feature, just a brain fart

Comment: Even so, I assume you'd have to use `this.qty` to access it.  Anyway, if it's working then great.  I won't bother you about it anymore.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you SO MUCH for helping me out. The missing link here was that I needed to return the $collections collection again in my update function. I really appreciate you taking the time today!

Comment: My pleasure!  Good luck.